# I launched a Window containing a UserControl from my MainWindowViewModel and I want to close that Window

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I'm launching a Window that contains a UserControl and I want to close that Window from the UserControl's ViewModel. What's the best and cleanest way to approach this while sticking with MVVM?

Ideally, I'd like to call the same command a Button with IsCancel calls when it closes the Window. I have no code tied to my cancel Button and it closes the Window perfectly.

Here's what I'm currently doing...

I launch the Window with the UserControl from MainWindowViewModel and I pass the MainWindowViewModel to the UserControl's ViewModel like this:

```
        Window window = new Window
        {
            Title = "Sign In",
            Height = 350,
            Width = 500,
            WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen,
            WindowStyle = WindowStyle.ToolWindow,
            ResizeMode = ResizeMode.NoResize,
            Content = new SignIn(mainWindowViewModel: this)
        };

        window.ShowDialog();
```

I'm just not too sure how to close the Window from the UserControl's ViewModel.

Comment: any joy with this? If my answer below didn't help, then do you want to elaborate more?

Comment: @olitee I actually created a property called ChildWindow in MainWindowViewModel and set the windows I launch to that. Then, because I have access to the MainWindowViewModel from the new window, I can just call MainWindowViewModel.ChildWindow.Close() and it shuts down whatever window is open.

Answer (score 0):

Filling in quite a few blanks here, but assuming that 'SignIn' is your viewmodel, you could pass an Action/callback that your SignIn viewmodel can invoke to close the Window:

```
Window window = new Window
{
    Title = "Sign In",
    Height = 350,
    Width = 500,
    WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen,
    WindowStyle = WindowStyle.ToolWindow,
    ResizeMode = ResizeMode.NoResize,
};

window.Content = new SignIn(mainWindowViewModel: this, 
    closeWindowAction: (isCancelled) =>
    {
        window.DialogResult = !isCancelled;
        window.Close();
    });

window.ShowDialog();
```

So that you can maintain some degree of loose coupling between your view models, and assuming your SignIn VM class looks something like this:

```
public class SignIn
{
    private readonly Action<bool> _closeWindowAction;

    public SignIn(MainWindowViewModel mainWindowViewModel, Action<bool> closeWindowAction)
    {
        _closeWindowAction = closeWindowAction;
    }

    public void CloseWindow(bool isCancelled)
    {
        _closeWindowAction.Invoke(isCancelled);
    }
}
```

Although, I'm not 100% clear on why you're passing the MainWindowViewModel into your SignIn view model.

If you want to keep things really clean in terms of MVVM, then I tend to create an `IDialogService` interface which I can use to display message boxes, modals etc, within my viewmodels - which delegates the creation and management of the `Window` to some implementation of that service. The end result is that the view model has no knowledge of HOW a modal or dialog is going to be displayed.

If you're interested - there are libraries that you can use such as https://github.com/FantasticFiasco/mvvm-dialogs - or roll your own.

Comment: As the author of the referenced library, if you feel that we lack a sample on how to solve your specific use case using MvvmDialogs, just create an issue and we'll sort it out.